# Interpolation between $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ and $\operatorname{BMO}(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces, interpolation-theory

Consider a measurable, real function $f$ defined on $\mathbb R^n$ which belongs to $L^p(\mathbb R^n)\cap \operatorname{BMO}(\mathbb R^n)$, for some $1\leq p<\infty$. An interpolation inequality exists (see e.g. [this paper](https://ejde.math.txstate.edu/Volumes/2019/56/dao.pdf)) that reads
$$ \|f\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^n)}\leq C \|f\|^{p/q}_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)}\|f\|^{1-p/q}_{\operatorname{BMO}(\mathbb R^n)} $$
for any $p<q<\infty$, where the constant $C$ does not depend on the choice of $f$.

Now, it seems to me that the constant $C$ has to depend on $q$ and goes to infinity as $q\to\infty^-$. My thoughts are: if $C$ did not depend on $q$, it would follow that
$$ \limsup_{q\to\infty^-}\|f\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^n)}<\infty, $$
which would imply that $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$. But this is definitely not true, since for instance it is well-known that the Sobolev space $H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)=W^{n/2,2}(\mathbb R^n)$ (defined using the Fourier transform) is contained in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)\cap\operatorname{BMO}(\mathbb R^n)$ but not in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ (please correct me if I have overlooked something).

My question is then, do you know a reference discussing the above inequality and the dependence of the constant $C$ on $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Some thoughts that might help you. If I remember well, $BMO = F^0_{\infty,2}$ and $L^p = F^0_{p,2}$ are both of the form Triebel-Lizorkin spaces. I think also there is a paper of Mario Millman about the continuity of interpolation spaces at the boundary, and the good scaling there.